DataGrip. How to utilize Geo Viewer
I have a list of Geometries, and I am trying to plot them on a map. I see DataGrip has a 'Geo Viewer' option, but not sure how to use correctly. I have my Geo's in my query, and if I go to 'Show Geo Viewer' none of my points show up.
query results
What am I doing wrong?

Are they the right kind of "geo"? The Geo Viewer expects geography data with spatial reference ID 4326. How have you created those binary values?

That was it! I was not using the correct geo. I made a geo point with
select id, geography ::Point(lat, lon, 4326) as geoloc
from geotable
where lat is not null
and lon is not null
then did the geo-viewer and it worked!
Thank you @AlwaysLearning, this comment helped a lot
